# How to create a unification model in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have two hive tables

table_1:which has 5 columns as shown below

```
    +----------+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+
    | ios_id   | column1| column2   | column3   | column4 | 
    +----------+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+
    | 1        | ios_1  | ios_2     | ios_3     | ios_4   |        
    | 2        | ios_1  | ios_2     | ios_3     | ios_4   |        
    | 3        | ios_1  | ios_2     | ios_3     | ios_4   |        
    | 4        | ios_1  | ios_2     | ios_3     | ios_4   |        
    | 5        | ios_1  | ios_2     | ios_3     | ios_4   |        
    +----------+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

table_2:has 5 columns as shown in below

```
    +------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
    | android_id | column1    | column2    | column3    | column4   |
    +------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
    | 6          | android_1  | android_2  | android_3  | android_4 |        
    | 7          | android_1  | android_2  | android_3  | android_4 |        
    | 8          | android_1  | android_2  | android_3  | android_4 |        
    | 9          | android_1  | android_2  | android_3  | android_4 |        
    | 10         | android_1  | android_2  | android_3  | android_4 |        
    +------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

The output table should be like this .both android_id and ios_id should come under id column

table_3(Output table)

```
    +---------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
    | id      | column1    | column2    | column3    | column4   | 
    +---------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
    | 1       | ios_1      | ios_2      | ios_3      | ios_4     |        
    | 2       | ios_1      | ios_2      | ios_3      | ios_4     |        
    | 3       | ios_1      | ios_2      | ios_3      | ios_4     |        
    | 4       | ios_1      | ios_2      | ios_3      | ios_4     |        
    | 5       | ios_1      | ios_2      | ios_3      | ios_4     |
    | 6       | android_1  | android_2  | android_3  | android_4 |       
    | 7       | android_1  | android_2  | android_3  | android_4 |        
    | 8       | android_1  | android_2  | android_3  | android_4 |        
    | 9       | android_1  | android_2  | android_3  | android_4 |        
    | 10      | android_1  | android_2  | android_3  | android_4 |         
    +---------+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Hint:  `UNION ALL`.

Comment: try something like `select ios_id as id,... from table_1 union all select android_id as id,... from table_2`